RuntimeError: shape '[1, 13, 13]' is invalid for input of size 13
I use LSTM-Autoencoder, took the model by this guy https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_J2MrBSvsJfOcVmYAN2-WSp36BtsFZCa#scrollTo=vgUChGd_A-Bv,
for anomaly detection in time series
and got problem my input has 13-features and torch tensor look like that :
> tensor(\[0.2978, 0.1695, 0.0114, 0.0026, 0.0711, 0.0705, 0.1244, 0.2143, 0.3186,
> 0.5806, 0.4158, 0.2525, 0.6769\]),

in train process:
model, history = train_model(
    model, 
    train_dataset, 
    val_dataset, 
    n_epochs=100,
)


RuntimeError: shape '[1, 13, 13]' is invalid for input of size 13

problem in shapes, but don't understand which shape should be changed
the model is here:
class Encoder(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, seq_len, n_features, embedding_dim=64):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()

    self.seq_len, self.n_features = seq_len, n_features
    self.embedding_dim, self.hidden_dim = embedding_dim, 2 * embedding_dim

    self.rnn1 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=n_features,
      hidden_size=self.hidden_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )
    
    self.rnn2 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=self.hidden_dim,
      hidden_size=embedding_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    x = x.reshape((1, self.seq_len, self.n_features))

    x, (_, _) = self.rnn1(x)
    x, (hidden_n, _) = self.rnn2(x)

    return hidden_n.reshape((self.n_features, self.embedding_dim))

class Decoder(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, seq_len, input_dim=64, n_features=1):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()

    self.seq_len, self.input_dim = seq_len, input_dim
    self.hidden_dim, self.n_features = 2 * input_dim, n_features

    self.rnn1 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=input_dim,
      hidden_size=input_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )

    self.rnn2 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=input_dim,
      hidden_size=self.hidden_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )

    self.output_layer = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, n_features)

  def forward(self, x):
    x = x.repeat(self.seq_len, self.n_features)
    x = x.reshape((self.n_features, self.seq_len, self.input_dim))

    x, (hidden_n, cell_n) = self.rnn1(x)
    x, (hidden_n, cell_n) = self.rnn2(x)
    x = x.reshape((self.seq_len, self.hidden_dim))

    return self.output_layer(x)

class RecurrentAutoencoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, seq_len, n_features, embedding_dim=64):
        super(RecurrentAutoencoder, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = Encoder(seq_len, n_features, embedding_dim).to(device)
        self.decoder = Decoder(seq_len, embedding_dim, n_features).to(device)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)

        return x
model = RecurrentAutoencoder(seq_len_train, n_features_train, 128)
model = model.to(device)
model
> RecurrentAutoencoder(
>   (encoder): Encoder(
>     (rnn1): LSTM(13, 256, batch_first=True)
>     (rnn2): LSTM(256, 128, batch_first=True)
>   )
>   (decoder): Decoder(
>     (rnn1): LSTM(128, 128, batch_first=True)
>     (rnn2): LSTM(128, 256, batch_first=True)
>     (output_layer): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=13, bias=True)
>   )

with 1-dim shape this code works well
with 13-dim shape i have no ideas
